# Question about controllers, dependent models, and controller functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm thoroughly confused from all the documentation online. I'm creating a database program that keeps track of orders. I've already setup the has_one, belongs_to, and has_many associations in the model and I can verify their relationship with my sqlbrowswer.

Here's an rough illustration of the models.

[Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfMz1.png)

**Each order has only one product, one service, one bill, and each bill can have many charges. The same product may appear in different orders, but each order would be unique.**

I also have an order_observer model to create dependent models of the product

`class OrderObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :order
    def after_create(order)
        Product.create! :order_id => order.id
        Service.create! :order_id => order.id
        Bill.create! :order_id => order.id
    end
end`

Here's what my product class and order class look like:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :order
end


class Order < ApplicationRecord
has_one :product, dependent: :destroy
has_one :bill, dependent: :destroy
has_one :service, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill
accepts_nested_attributes_for :service
end
```

Now, what I'm confused on is how to update the dependent models. Should I implement multiple controllers for each model or just one controller to handle the whole thing?

Right now all I have in my main controller is:

```
 def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)   
 end
 def edit 
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
 end
 def update
 end
```

I would appreciate any tips or guidance. 
Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to define the relation between Product and Order, it's N:N relation. So you need see this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: As I said, I already setup the relationships between product and order.

Comment: Would one product (e.g. "Large Green Widget") ever appear on more than one order?

Comment: Kinda depends on how you want to set up the endpoints... do you want users to create all the records with a single request? If so, you should make a single controller action. You can consider the controller action to basically be a route handler

Answer (score 0):

> Now, what I'm confused on is how to update the dependent models. Should I implement multiple controllers for each model or just one controller to handle the whole thing?

You can do this whatever you want, but you should always remember the idea 'resources', In this case, each model represents a resource, so you should do it separately.
The Rails program is based on resources, as you can see that in 'routes.rb'.